# Disabling hyperfootnotes when using pdfx package

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, pdfx

I have a problem setting certain options of the `hyperref` package when also using `pdfx`:

The `pdfx` manual states that `pdfx` already loads the `hyperref` package and that therefore custom options should be set using `\hypersetup{<options>}`. However, there are certain options for `hyperref` that need to be provide at loading time. Among them is the `hyperfootnotes` option which I would like to set.

If I try set the option using `\hypersetup` I get a warning that the option was ignored ("Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used ..."). A minimal  working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{hyperfootnotes=false}

\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}
\end{document}
```

If I instead try to pass the option by loading the `hyperref` package myself (`\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`) after loading the `pdfx` package, I get an "Option clash" error message. Loading `hyperref` before `pdfx` also doesn't work.

My question is: Is there a way to tell `pdfx` to load `hyperref` with the desired `hyperfootnotes` option? Alternatively, is there a way to manually patch the `\footnote` command to not produce a hyperlink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\PassOptionsToPackage` before loading `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Emil You're welcome. If this solved your problem consider accepting this answer by clicking the green checkmark button next to the voting arrows.